# Running a script before absolutely everything

Tags: functions, hooks

I want to run a script before any Wordpress stuff kicks in.

I know it's wrong but currently I have my function in the `index.php` file before the below code:

```
{{{MY FUNCTION IS HERE}}}

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['country'])) {
    $reader = new Reader('db/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb');

    $record = $reader->country($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    $_SESSION['country'] =  $record->country->isoCode;
}

{{{MY FUNCTION ENDS HERE}}}


/**
* Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
*/

/**
* Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
*
* @var bool
*/

define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

This obviously gets overidden whenever Wordpress updates so how can I include my function safely and correctly please?

I've tried with the following in my themes `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_script' );

function my_script() {

      // my script here
}
```

But that's not soon enough, unless I'm making a mistake?

Can anyone help please?

Many thanks

Comment: The earliest hook I can think of is `muplugins_loaded`. Have you tried this one?

Comment: What does your script do? Why does it need to be run before everything else? Is there a technical reason?

Comment: I want to initialise a session so it needs to be before the headers are sent.

Answer (score 1):

`init` is not the first action to run on a WordPress install. Here is a basic rundown of a typical stack order.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Try hooking into `muplugins_loaded'. I don't believe it is conditional, so it should run every time.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/muplugins_loaded

```
<?php
  add_action( 'muplugins_loaded', 'my_script' );

  function my_script() {
    // my script here
  }
```

Comment: Ahh ok thank you, I'll give that at try later. I'm trying to initalise a session so my function needs to run before the headers are sent.

Comment: I tried this and USE cannot be used within a function so it doesn't work. I've updated my original question to include the function that I want to run. Hopefully you can help

Answer (score 0):

The first PHP file that WordPress loads and doesn't overwrite on update is `wp-config.php`. At this point, WordPress is not loaded. So you can put your functions at the beginning of that file.

Comment: I've updated my original question to include the function that I want to run. Does this help in any way or would you still suggest that I add in in the wp-config file?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place your code in any file (with a `.php` extension that is) in `/wp-content/mu-plugins/`

All PHP files in that directory (but not subdirectories) will automatically be run before any hooks are fired (yes even before `muplugins_loaded`.)

This is arguably a better place for sitewide customizations than a theme `functions.php` anyway so they will persist if you change themes.

Comment: I tried that and whatever .php file I include in that directory (even an empty one) causes the site to error. I've updated my original question to include the function that I want to run. Hopefully you can help

Comment: Check the file owner/group permissions on the `mu-plugins` directory to make sure they match the rest of your installation (since you probably just created it). There is no good reason for auto-included must-use plugins files to just fail. If it is not this, you can check your error logs to find out what the error is more specifically.